# Finding symmetric difference of 2 sets separating them by origin

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, set

I have two sets:

```
>>> a = {1,2,3}
>>> b = {2,3,4,5,6}
```

And I would like to get **two** new sets with **non** common elements, first set containing elements from `a` and second from `b`, like `({1}, {4,5,6})`, or like:

```
>>> c = a&b # Common elements
>>> d = a^b # Symmetric difference
>>> (a-b, b-a)
({1}, {4, 5, 6})
>>> (a-c, b-c)
({1}, {4, 5, 6})
>>> (a&d, b&d)
({1}, {4, 5, 6})
```

My problem is that I'm going to use this on large number of sha1 hashes and I'm worried about performance. *What is proper way of doing this efficiently*?

Note: `a` and `b` are going to have around 95% of elements common, 1% will be in `a` and 4% in `b`.

Comment: `a-b, b-a` is the way I have done this in the past, but it was for readability more than performance.  why don't you try a few of the methods and run them each through `timeit`?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to beat `a-b, b-a`.  All Python has to do is evaluate the names `a` and `b` and then do a binary subtract with `-` (you can see the exact breakdown with [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis)).  The actual function however that creates the new sets is written in C, which will outperform anything written in Python.

Comment: I think `a-b, b-a` will be O(n) and I can't imagine any way to get better than `O(n)` anyway.  Doing it with one iteration as opposed to twice will not change the complexity.

Comment: It is an interesting question anyway, I often need to do this when finding out which elements to add / modify / delete when updating a many-to-many on relational databases

Answer (score 2):

Methods I've mentioned in the question has following performance:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a-b; b-a', 'a=set(range(0,1500000)); b=set(range(1000000, 2000000))', number=1000)
135.45828826893307
>>> timeit.timeit('c=a&b; a-c; b-c', 'a=set(range(0,1500000)); b=set(range(1000000, 2000000))', number=1000)
189.98522938665735
>>> timeit.timeit('d=a^b; a&d; b&d', 'a=set(range(0,1500000)); b=set(range(1000000, 2000000))', number=1000)
238.35084129583106
```

So most effective way seems to be using `(a-b, b-a)` method.

*I'm posting this as a reference so other answers would add new methods, not compare the ones I've found.*

---

#### Python implemented function

Just out of curiosity I've tried implementing own python function to do this (that works on pre-sorted iterators):

```
def symmetric_diff(l1,l2):
    # l1 and l2 has to be sorted and contain comparable elements
    r1 = []
    r2 = []
    i1 = iter(l1)
    i2 = iter(l2)

    try:
        e1 = next(i1)
    except StopIteration: return ([], list(i2))
    try:
        e2 = next(i2)
    except StopIteration: return ([e1] + list(i1), [])

    try:
        while True: 
            if e1 == e2:
                e1 = next(i1)
                e2 = next(i2)
            elif e1 > e2:
                r2.append(e2)
                e2 = next(i2)
            else:
                r1.append(e1)
                e1 = next(i1)

    except StopIteration:
        if e1==e2:
            return (r1+list(i1), r2+list(i2))
        elif e1 > e2:
            return (r1+[e1]+list(i1), r2+list(i2))
        else:   
            return (r1+list(i1), r2+[e2]+list(i2))
```

Compared to other methods, this one has quite low performance:

```
t = timeit.Timer(lambda: symmetric_diff(a,b))
>>> t.timeit(1000)
542.3225249653769
```

So unless some other method is implemented somewhere (some library for working with sets) I think using two sets difference *is* the most efficient way of doing this.